How to specify the column and data property in jspreadsheet ce when a property is another object
The outer object has properties name, id, age, and company. The company property is another object with properties name and location.
var table = jexcel(document.getElementById('spreadsheet'), {        
data:[
    { name:'Jorge', id:'3', age:'40',company:{name:'nokia',location:'us'} },
    { name:'Robert', id:'4', age:'48',company:{name:'nokia',location:'us'} },
    { name:'Santos', id:'5', age:'32',company:{name:'nokia',location:'us'} },
],
columns: [
    { type:'text', width:300, name:'id', title:'id' },
    { type:'text', width:100, name:'name', title:'name' },
    { type:'text', width:100, name:'age', title:'age' },
    { type:'text', width:100, data:'company.name', title:'company name' },
    { type:'text', width:100, data:'company.location', title:'company location' },
 ]
});

and the result table looks like this:

An example of this issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/sridharnetha/vf0tknxb/2/

Perhaps it is Pro feature only?

Customizing the script by using a method updateTable is working as I expected.
data = [
    { name:'Jorge', id:'3', age:'40',company:{name:'nokia',location:'us'} },
    { name:'Robert', id:'4', age:'48',company:{name:'nokia',location:'us'} },
    { name:'Santos', id:'5', age:'32',company:{name:'nokia',location:'us'} },
];

jspreadsheet(document.getElementById('my-spreadsheet'), {
    data:data,
    allowInsertColumn: false,

    columns: [
        { type:'text', width:50, name:'id', title:'id' },
        { type:'text', width:100, name:'name', title:'name' },
        { type:'text', width:50, name:'age', title:'age' },        
        { type:'object', width:100, data:'company.name', title:'company name' },
        { type:'text', width:100, data:'company.location', title:'company location' },
    ],

    updateTable:function(instance, cell, col, row, val, label, cellName) {
        if (col == 3) {
            // alert(JSON.stringify(val));
            cell.innerHTML = val.name;
        }
    }
});

